# Represent directory tree as JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, data-structures, tree

Is there any easy way to generate such a JSON? I found `os.walk()` and `os.listdir()`, so I may do recursive descending into directories and build a python object, well, but it sounds like reinventing a wheel, maybe someone knows working code for such a task?

```
{
  "type": "directory",
  "name": "hello",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "directory",
      "name": "world",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "one.txt"
        },
        {
          "type": "file",
          "name": "two.txt"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "file",
      "name": "README"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I don't think that this task is a "wheel" (so to speak). But it is something which you can easily achieve by means of the tools you mentioned:

```
import os
import json

def path_to_dict(path):
    d = {'name': os.path.basename(path)}
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        d['type'] = "directory"
        d['children'] = [path_to_dict(os.path.join(path,x)) for x in os.listdir\
(path)]
    else:
        d['type'] = "file"
    return d

print json.dumps(path_to_dict('.'))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this recursively

Comment: This is recursive.

Answer (score 27):

On Linux, the command-line tool [`tree`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) can be used, although it is *not* installed by default. The output is almost identical to that required by the OP, using the flag `-J` for JSON output (which can then be streamed to a file for example):

```
tree -J folder
```

On OSX, this tool can be installed via [Homebrew](http://brewformulas.org/Tree).

Comment: I think you should provide more information. Currently it is more a comment than a real answer... ;)

Comment: This is interesting and it works. Starting a separate process and reading its output is Linux-specific and not purely Python, though.

Comment: I don't see the `-J` flag on the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree). Is there a certain version of `tree` that has the json output?

Comment: this just saved me a ton of time (angularJS + gulp migration to webpack), thank you

Answer (score 2):

I just had to do this (well, almost) so hit this page but the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25226267/916373) doesn't recurse into subdirectories.

So this version only handles directories, not files, but you could add those.

First generate a nested python dict:

```py
def fs_tree(root):
    results = {}
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(root):
        parts = dirpath.split(os.sep)
        curr = results
        for p in parts:
            curr = curr.setdefault(p, {})
    return results
```

Secondly dump that to json using the `json` module.