# custom jstree JSON data parse into tree

Tags: javascript, json, jstree

i have a simple JSON data which is this :

```
[  
   "env/child1/env/key1",
   "env/child1/key1",
   "env/child1/key2",
   "env/child1/",
   "env/child2/key1",
   "env/child2/key2",
   "env/child2/",
   "env/"
]
```

how can i make jsTree understands this tree and draw the tree ?

- env

  - child1

    - key1
    - key2

do i need to write a custom parsing function or is there a ready way for that.

Comment: Judging from the jsTree website, you would first need to instantiate the DOM according to the tree you want to build. Do you have the code where you do this? Did you place the jstree initialisation in the $(document).ready?

Comment: i don't have anything ready , maybe some guidance that what to do so that i can start
ps: i am using the demo files from the original jstree package

Comment: Can you change the way that JSON looks? Can you expand on it?

Comment: this is the json that i get it's  structure is fixed  and can not be changed

Comment: JS tree tell you how you should structure your data: https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/. So you should probably change your array to follow that format.

Comment: exactly .. and thats what i want to do .. which i am lost how to convert my json structure from file path alike to json alike

Comment: Please post the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: i was planning to iterate over the json array and do mkdir -p on linux and then by using this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226208/represent-directory-tree-as-json  and then parse the correct json to a jstree compatible version

Comment: Do you want to mkdir on the server or on the client?

Comment: there was no need for mkdir, thanks for your help .. i have finished my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tree = {
    'core' : {
        'data' : [
        ]
    } 
}

data = [  
   "env/child1/env/key1",
   "env/child1/key1",
   "env/child1/key2",
   "env/child1/",
   "env/child2/key1",
   "env/child2/key2",
   "env/child2/",
   "env/"
];

minlen = -1;
picked = "";
for(i =0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].length < minlen || minlen == -1) {
        minlen = data[i].length;
        picked = data[i];
    }
}

tree.core.data.push({ "id" : picked, "parent" : "#", "text" : picked })
xdata = data
xdata.splice(xdata.indexOf(picked), 1)

for(i =0; i<xdata.length; i++) {
    name = xdata[i]
    parent = ""
    if(name.substr(name.length-1,1) == '/') {
        xname = name.substr(0,name.length-1);
        parent = xname.substr(0,xname.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
    } else {
        parent = name.substr(0,name.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
    }
    tree.core.data.push({ "id" : name, "parent" : parent, "text" : name })
}
console.log(tree);
```

I followed the alternative JSON format.

Result:

```
{
  "core": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "env/",
        "parent": "#",
        "text": "env/"
      },
      {
        "id": "env/child1/env/key1",
        "parent": "env/child1/env/",
        "text": "env/child1/env/key1"
      },
      {
        "id": "env/child1/key1",
        "parent": "env/child1/",
        "text": "env/child1/key1"
      },
      {
        "id": "env/child1/key2",
        "parent": "env/child1/",
        "text": "env/child1/key2"
      },
      {
        "id": "env/child1/",
        "parent": "env/",
        "text": "env/child1/"
      },
      {
        "id": "env/child2/key1",
        "parent": "env/child2/",
        "text": "env/child2/key1"
      },
      {
        "id": "env/child2/key2",
        "parent": "env/child2/",
        "text": "env/child2/key2"
      },
      {
        "id": "env/child2/",
        "parent": "env/",
        "text": "env/child2/"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked until i had to create another folder next to the root env

Answer (score -1):

The above data missing parent "env/child1/env/" for child "env/child1/env/key1"
1. correct as follow:
data = [ 
   "env/child1/env/" 
   "env/child1/env/key1",
   "env/child1/key1",
   "env/child1/key2",
   "env/child1/",
   "env/child2/key1",
   "env/child2/key2",
   "env/child2/",
   "env/"
];

2. The complete code for parent getting the children's values as below:
   https://github.com/peterhchen/700-jstree/blob/master/08_PathJSON/0802_PathChild2ParentValueHier.htm